# Configuring NAT through iptables

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I want to change this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
178.212.120.5   192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth2.2
208.67.222.222  192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth2.2
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2.2
192.168.10.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
239.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 br0
default         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2.2
```

into this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
178.212.120.5   192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 ra0
208.67.222.222  192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 ra0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ra0
192.168.10.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
239.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 br0
default         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ra0
```

and configure NAT the way that:

1. Public NAT interface is `ra0` with IP `192.168.1.3`
2. NAT internal subnet is `192.168.10.0/24` on `br0`

The problem I got is that I know how to use Linux `route` and `ifconfig` commands but I know nothing about `iptables`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "rough and ready" answer would be to use route and ifconfig to set up the ra interface and routing, and then issue an iptables command -

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ra0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This will masquerade (all) traffic going out ra0 but not br0.  I note however that the "NAT interface of ra0 is not actually a real world IP address, so either you will be doing double nat or that IP address is incorrect.